# Migrate MySQL to MS-SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, amazon-rds, database-migration

Can I perform migration from AWS RDS MySQL 8.0 to AWS RDS MS-SQL Server 2019 with the help of AWS DMS?

I find several documents and youtube videos on AWS DMS with different combination of DMS Source and Target Endpoints, but couldn't able to find any documents for MySQL to MS-SQL server migration with AWS DMS.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned that Mysql 8.0 is supported as source.[Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Sources.html)

> MySQL versions 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, and 8.0.
>
> ##### Note
>
> Support for MySQL 8.0 as a source is available in AWS DMS versions 3.4.0 and later, >except when the transaction payload is compressed.

SQL Server 2019 is supported as target. [Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Targets.html)

> Microsoft SQL Server versions 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017, and 2019 for the Enterprise, Standard, Workgroup, and Developer editions. The Web and Express editions are not supported.
>
> ##### Note
>
> Support for Microsoft SQL Server version 2019 as a target is
> available in AWS DMS versions 3.3.2 and later.

You can use DMS to move from source to target, as mentioned in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Endpoints.html)